# Selenium setup on Windows for Chrome and IE

Tags: windows, internet-explorer, selenium

As far as i understand, there are two possible ways of setting up a selenium server (just a node) on windows:

1. As a windows service
2. Using the task scheduler to start the server running within a local user account

However, using the service way (where no desktop is available) the Internet Explorer can not be used.

Therefore, i created a local user account and a scheduled task to start the selenium server at startup connected to the user account (using the selenium-standalone package, `selenium-standalone start --drivers.ie.arch=ia32`).

Unfortunately, i ran into the "Session 0" problem, which requires a real login for the local user account. Otherwise, i would receive a timeout error for 
Chrome and black screenshots for IE and have the max resolution of 1024x768...

However, with a active user session, i still get the timeout error for IE (Chrome works). The browser makes the initial GET request (retrieving the login page) but keeps stuck after this (next step would be to fill the form with credentials using protractor).

I read about the [Headless Selenium for Windows](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win) that gives me some connecting layer between the driver and the GUI. Though, i do not know if this would help and how to integrate this into the selenium-standalone package.

So, my question is, what is the missing puzzle in the setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, there are two ways to accomplish the setup. However, only with using a scheduled task i was able to workaround the session 0 issue (as @Cosmin stated). Using NSSM and FireDeamon Pro was a dead end.

I reconfigured the server, to automatically login the local user account and changed the scheduled task, to run if and only if this user is logged in (starting Selenium). So, after the server starts, the user gets logged in, which triggers the task scheduler (at this point a simple startup script should work, too) to start Selenium.

And for the screen resolution problem: The VM setup uses Hyper-V, where the default resolution is 1024x768. This could easily be changed (to the max resolution the screen adapter is providing) to 1600x1200.

PS: The [Headless Selenium for Windows](https://github.com/kybu/headless-selenium-for-win) did not work either (can not be used with Protractor). However, even this is no longer necessary. IE works this way.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to move away from Session 0, as Chrome is trying to move away from Session 0 too in the near future.

You can find further references of this here (comment 21 in the link below, but actually the whole thread is a good read in respect to this subject): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=615396#c21

You could try using this setup for Chrome for now, however there is no guarantee that it will still work while Chrome is started Session 0.

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddArguments("test-type");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
chromeOptions.AddArguments("no-sandbox");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);
```

I had the same issues with using Microsoft's Test Agent, and moving the agent from a windows service to a process, solved all the issues and headaches that I had.

Comment: AFAIK this setup (with active user session) is a workaround for the session 0 problem. I have no problems with the Chrome setup, but with IE.

So you suggesting to use a windows service (via i.e. NSSM) instead of the task scheduler approach?

Comment: https://support.firedaemon.com/kb/a242/what-is-session-0-what-do-i-need-to-know-about-it.aspx

Comment: Everything started by a interactive windows service will run in session 0